# How can I replace full lines where patterns are matched in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am new to powershell, so the mistake may be obvious but my code is below. I am attempting to write a script to replace all lines containing IP addresses on the 100.1, 100.2, 100.3, 100.4 subnets and replace them with a line that says "Ignore. When my code is run, it simply writes the original line to the new file, and then prints the word ignore to the screen multiple times.

```
foreach ($line in $sources) {
    if($line -notlike "100.1.*" -and $line -notlike "100.2.*" -and $line -notlike "100.3.*" -and $line -notlike "100.4.*"){
        $line.Replace( $line, "Ignore");
        $line >> $outputFile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with a replace.  Just specify the static value.

```
foreach ($line in $sources) {
    if($line -notlike "100.1.*" -and $line -notlike "100.2.*" -and $line -notlike "100.3.*" -and $line -notlike "100.4.*") {
        "Ignore" >> $outputFile;
    } else {
        $line >> $outputFile;
    } 
}
```

I may have the logic backwards here.  Your description and code is confusing to me.  It's the opposite of how I'd write it.

Comment: Your logic made alot more sense than mine did, I just got caught up in all the different commands I was reading about I guess. Thanks for the help!